# Postfix restrict all incoming mail to certain domains, then allow all for specific user addresses

Tags: postfix

We use Postfix for company email address's given to employees... all are of the format username@example.com.

Basically I want to restrict all incoming mail to these addresses to only allow emails from the @example.com domain.

Simple enough I think however there are a select few supervisor addresses that need to be unrestricted (able to receive emails from any domain).

None of the answers I've found seem to answer this problem (Although I'm really weak when it comes to working with email settings)

snippit of /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
    permit_sasl_authenticated, 
    permit_mynetworks, 
    reject_unauth_destination, 
    check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access, 
    reject
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use restriction classes. See:

- http://www.postfix.net/postconf.5.html#smtpd_restriction_classes
- http://www.postfix.net/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html.

**For your case**

Now we have to create two classes, first one for supervisor class and second one for the rest of company.

#### The Setup

Define smtpd_restriction_classess in **main.cf**

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = mysupervisor
```

Set smtpd_recipient_restrictions in **main.cf**, place this line after `check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access,`

```
check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/mycompany.rules
```

This file `/etc/postfix/mycompany.rules`, will perform decision logic to select which address that belongs to `mysupervisor` class. So the content is

```
someone999@example.com    mysupervisor
someone123@example.com    mysupervisor
```

Then define rule for mysupervisor class in **main.cf**, so postfix will permit all address.

```
mysupervisor = permit
```

To check whether the email was coming from company domain (example.com), set rule `check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/insiders` after `check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/mycompany.rules`. The content of `/etc/postfix/insiders`

```
example.com OK
```

Now, **main.cf** hase become

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = mysupervisor
mysupervisor = permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
    permit_sasl_authenticated, 
    permit_mynetworks, 
    reject_unauth_destination, 
    check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access,
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/mycompany.rules,
    check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/insiders
    reject
```

#### How it works

For all email, postfix will apply the restriction until

```
check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access,
```

After that email will be checked against `mycompany.rules`. If the recipient was supervisor email, than permit it, otherwise postfix will perform last restriction `/etc/postfix/insiders`. If the sender is @example.com then permit it, otherwise reject it.